# Wildcard subdomain not using correct conf file

Tags: apache, subdomain, wildcard

I have a set up as follows:

All subdomains pointing to the server

sub1.example.com should load /var/www/sub1

sub2.example.com should load /var/www/sub2

Any random subdomain should load /var/www/shared

The problem is the shared.conf file is being ignored and instead using sub1 (or whichever one I move to the start of the .conf file list).

Here are my conf files in their order after running `ls -lv`

```
sub1.conf
sub2.conf
shared.conf
```

sub1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName sub1.example.com
        ServerAlias sub1.example.com
        <Directory /var/www/sub1/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1

</VirtualHost>
```

sub2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName sub2.example.com
        ServerAlias sub2.example.com
        <Directory /var/www/sub2/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/sub2

</VirtualHost>
```

shared.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        <Directory /var/www/shared/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/shared

</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried adding a random subdomain to the shared.conf file for Server Name, i.e.

```
ServerName shared-random.example.com
```

And also

```
ServerName *.example.com
```

I have also made sure to restart apache.

So when I put in any subdomain, e.g. blabla.example.com it always goes to sub1.conf.

I understand that the behaviour is to default to the first one, but only if there isnt a match. Why isnt shared.conf being considered a match?

Comment: Try adding a `ServerName *.example.com` in shared.conf.  Only a `ServerAlias` config is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately its still ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

change filename from `shared.conf` to `000-shared.conf`

use below config for 000-shared.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/shared

        <Directory /var/www/shared>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>
       

</VirtualHost>
```